# How to set the title of ProgressMonitorDialog

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using `ProgressMonitorDialog` to display a progress dialog for long running process.

```
Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();
shell.setText("HTML result loading");
shell.update();
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InterruptedException {
        monitor.beginTask(ResourceAssistant.getString(ViewAsHTML.class, "loadingHTMLResults"), //$NON-NLS-1$
                IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        while (!thread.getState().equals(Thread.State.TERMINATED)) {
            if (monitor.isCanceled()) {
                setCanceled(true);
                break;
            }
        }
        monitor.done();
    }
});
```

I want to change the title of the Progress Dialog. By default it is showing as "Progress information". How can I change this. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title is set in the `configureShell` method which you can override:

```
protected void configureShell(final Shell shell)
{
  super.configureShell(shell);

  shell.setText("your title");
}
```